# How to fix RecyclerView requiresFadingEdge and clipToOutline glitch

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclervView` with a rounded `Drawable` background and `.clipToOutline = true` in order to keep the overscroll animation inside the background. When I set `requiresFadingEdge="vertical"`, there's a glitch where the fading edge is; example below. How can I fix this? The issue doesn't appear when I set `.clipToOutline = false` or when I don't have a fading edge, but I would like both of these effects. Thanks for the help.

[image]

You can see the issue in the bottom corners of the blue `RecyclerView`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be fixed by setting a different layer type either in xml, or programatically when initialising your recyclerview:

**XML**

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layerType="hardware"
    ...
```

**Programatically**

```
recyclerView.setLayerType(VIEW.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null)
```

You can also use `LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE`, but it's better to use `LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE` for performance reasons.
Find out more about this 2 options in these docs:

- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE
- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE